# Identify what kind of waveform i get at an analog input

Tags: mplab, adc

I'm currently using MPLABX to code Pic16f877a, I use Proteus as a simulator, I have to identify what type of waveform I get at the analog input, my frequency is not fixed but I can store it. I wanted to use a full bridge rectifier so I get an input of 0-5V.

I was thinking I could check how much time it needs to get from 0 to 1V, from 1V to 2V, etc. for the square wave it would always be ~+5V.

I don't know if there's a better way of if this is even possible. I attach a piece of code that stores the frequency. [MPLABX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9jXr.png)

Comment: This looks like a job for the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)

Comment: I'm gonna look into it, thanks